# dynamic value to uibinder in gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am new to GWT and trying to making a page which is trying to inherit a composite widget but the value of the composite widget is dynamic.

My main page is somehting like:

```
         .....
         .....
         <g:Button>Open composite widget</g:button>
         .....
         .....
```

which is opening an another popup panel which is something like:

```
         .....
         <table>
            <tr><td>Top: <myCompany:userMeasurementUnit/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bottom: <myCompany:userMeasurementUnit/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Left: <myCompany:userMeasurementUnit/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Right: <myCompany:userMeasurementUnit/> </td></tr>
        </table>
```

the above should show us

```
         top (cm)
         bottom (cm)
         left (cm)
         right (cm)
```

But I don't know how to pass the values from main page to custom widget i.e usermeasurementunit

```
          <myCompany:userMeasurementUnit/>
```

My usermeasurementunit is something like:

UIBinder:

```
     <htmlpanel tag="span" ui:field="unit"/>
```

and the composit widget is

```
      usermeasurementunit extends Composite {

       public usermeasurementunit(){
           initwidget...
       }

       public onload() { 
         ...
       }

       }
```

Now I want to pass any measurement unit cm or inches or meters upon clicking button. I tried it using the event bus but it didnt help because when I click the button popuppanel is not on the screen and its not catching the event. If any one of you can help me regarding this I would be really thankful as I am really struggling with this thing.

kind regards

Answer (score 13):

First of all, you need to understand the object instantiation flow in GWT.

They call it "delayed binding", not "dynamic binding".

Uibinder xml file is a layout template. And the JAva source bean behind it is known in general programming terms as the "code-behind".

The role or purpose of the uibinder layout template is to off-load the laying-out (*on the internet many non-English speaking programmers write "lay-outing" which, though syntax-wise amusing, is the same thing*) so that the code-behind could be focused on controlling the layout's responses.

It's akin to the MVP attitude. View implementation separated from presentation control. You can write the code-behind error free without even knowing exactly the positions where those fields are laid out. You could even simply supply a template where the ui elements are not properly laid out so  as to concentrate on your code-behind first. Perhaps after that. one uibinder template for mobile while another for desktop - but they can share the same code-behind.

The values displayed effected by the uibinder template is determined once-and-for-all during uibind. There is no dynamic binding of a uibinder field to the ever changing value of an object/variable declared in the code-behind.

To dynamically change/propagate the values of a uibinder field after uibind, you have to deliberately set its value in the code-behind or write a listener to detect its change.

```
public class Graceland {

  @UiField
  Label pressure;

  @UiField
  Button reset;

  public void setPressure(int value) {
    pressure.setText(value);
  }

  @UiHandler("reset")
  void nameDoesNotMatter(ClickEvent ev) {
    pressure.setText(default);
  }
}
```

GWT.create() generates the Java source for the template during compile time. GWT.create is not a run-time function.

@UiField and @UiHandler are bound to the uifield in the template during uibind.

The role of uibind() is mostly not run-time but compile time too. Though, its finality is realised during run-time, all the javascript code and respective values to construct the objects are generated during compile time and executed once and only once during uibind at run-time.

Therefore, the intention is not to be able to completely replace the dynamic role of the code-behind but simply to free it from the task of laying-out, so that we the programmer could have a clean piece of code-behind being smudged as little as possible with the spaghetti source of the layout.

However, if you wish to "dynamically" affect the value of a uibinder field during bind time,then `Ui:with` is your friend.

```
package z.mambazo;
public class Graceland {
  ....
  String initialPressure(){
    /* "dynamically" obtain the pressure from the
     * pressure gauge in the petroleum distillation stack
     * during uibind
     */
  }
}
```

Graceland.ui.xml:

```
<ui:UiBinder blah...blah>
  <ui:with type="z.mambazo" field="zulu"/>
  <g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:Label
      ui:field="pressure"
      text="the temperature is :{zulu.initialPressure}"/>
  </g:VerticalPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The ui:with bean does not have to be the template's code-behind. Either the ui:with bean has an no-argument constructor or you have to supply ui:with tag with attributes corresponding to the constructor arguments.

You have to take note that in order to use ui:with, the init value must be declared in the value attribute not in the tag text.

```
<g:Label
  ui:field="pressure"
  text="the temperature is : {zulu.initialPressure}"/>
```

Not

```
<g:Label ui:field="pressure">
  the temperature is : {zulu.initialPressure}
</g:Label>
```

The second way, would simply reproduce the text as is.

However, you could also do it this way:

```
<g:HtmlPanel>
  the temperature is :&nbsp;
  <g:Label ui:field="pressure"
    text="{zulu.initialPressure}"/>
</g:HtmlPanel>
```

Also, be reminded that all GWT UI Java code, even the interim generated ones, are all translated into browser Javascript. So, whatever class you reference with ui:with must be in Java source code not Java byte code. And those source code must not at any time down the calling chain call byte code.

Comment: Seems you've left out the class name in your ui:with type.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are [shared resources](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder?hl=de#Share_resource_instances). Here is an example:

MeasurementConstants.java:

```
package com.acme.client;

public class MeasurementConstants {

    private final String measurementUnit;

    public MeasurementConstants(String measurementUnit) {
        this.measurementUnit = measurementUnit;
    }

    public String measurementUnit() {
        return measurementUnit;
    }

}
```

UiBinderMeasurement.java:

```
package com.acme.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiFactory;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class UiBinderMeasurement extends Composite {

    private static UiBinderI18nUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(UiBinderI18nUiBinder.class);
    private MeasurementConstants constants;

    interface UiBinderI18nUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, UiBinderMeasurement> {
    }

    public UiBinderMeasurement(MeasurementConstants constants) {
        this.constants = constants;
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiFactory
    public MeasurementConstants getConstants() {
        return constants;
    }

}
```

UiBinderMeasurement.ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <ui:with type="com.acme.client.MeasurementConstants" field="constants"></ui:with>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <table>
            <tr><td><g:Label text="Top ({constants.measurementUnit}):" /> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><g:Label text="Bottom ({constants.measurementUnit}):" /> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><g:Label text="Left ({constants.measurementUnit}):" /> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><g:Label text="Right ({constants.measurementUnit}):" /> </td></tr>
        </table>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
new UiBinderMeasurement(new MeasurementConstants("cm"))
```